# Serializing and deserializing an object as an ID

Tags: c#, serialization

Sorry if the title is a bit confusing, but I couldn't think of a better one.

The idea is that I have a central object repository that can fetch objects by IDs, and these objects should not be serialized. But there are several references to the objects, which should be serialized, but only as an ID, and then deserialized from an ID using the repository.

So I thought of implementing the `ISerializable` interface for my object, so that it stores the ID in `GetObjectData`, and so that it restores the object from ID when deserializing. The problem is that deserializing is done in the constructor, so I can't return an existing object... How would I go around this? Or maybe other suggestions on how to do this?

Edit - seems to be unclear, so I'll try to clarify.

```
public class Ref {
    MyObj obj;
}

public class MyObj {
    string id;
    string objData;

    public static MyObj GetObj(string id) {
        // reads MyObj from a file or web service based on ID
        // caches objects as well
    }    
}
```

Now, in my program, I have several instances of `Ref`, which reference different `MyObj`s. I want to serialize these `Ref` objects, without actually serializing `MyObj`, but instead I'd like to serialize only the ID, which I can later use to fetch the object when deserializing.

I'd hope to do something like this:

```
[Serializable]
public class MyObj : ISerializable {
// code from before ...

public MyObj (SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext ctxt) {
        return MyObj.GetObj(info.GetString("id")); // this is not possible since this is a constructor and not a factory!
}

public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext ctxt) {
    info.AddValue("id", this.id);
}
```

}

Comment: too vague, but you can create a hashtable/dictionary save ID as the key and as a value you can save whole object. you can fetch actual object by ID.

Comment: It sounds like you may have an inherent problem with your architecture.  What are you trying to accomplish?  Not technically, but what is this serialization plan of yours trying to achieve, as an end result?

Comment: [DataContractSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) has support for serializing references and restoring them, but only within the context of a single object graph (which makes sense, as otherwise how could it remember how the IDs map to references?)  There are some subtleties here, though, as you need to create specific DTOs with `[DataMember]` attributes for this to work and you also need to be careful with inherited classes.)

Comment: I'm working on a game, and this is meant to save the state of the game. A lot of the game info is static and is loaded from files when the game starts. If you upgrade to a newer version of the game, and the static info changes, I want the old save files to work well, as long as the dynamic objects (which are saved as part of the savegame) do not change.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an idea. Create a wrapper class, named ObjectHolder for example. Your other classes can reference this ObjectHolder, and this ObjectHolder references the actual objects in the repository. Override the serialization and deserialization logic of the ObjectHolder class. You will have many ObjectHolder references, instead of many copies of the same objects.

Here's another one. It works if you don't have too many classes. Store the object reference ID in a private field. Write a getter property that fetches the object from the repository. This way only the ID will ever be serialized and the object will always be fetched on the fly. Like this:

```
private string id; // serialized
public Whatever MyObject { // not serializer
    get { return Repository.Get(id); }
}
```

You see, if you go this way, you have to change your references in many places. With the ObjectHolder class, it gets a bit more simple because the object fetching logic is implemented in only one place.

Comment: I thought of this, and even started working on it, but found that it would mess my code up too much, because I've got tens of those references... It might also slow things up a bit, even though the lookup is cached, it still takes longer than a memory reference. This is definitely plan B if I can't find a better solution.